# Using variables of an object of a class?

Tags: java

I'm a java beginner and I got a problem.
I created an object of a class with

```
Object pw = Class.forName(nameNeu).newInstance();
```

Now I need to access on a varibale of the class I created the object from.
Is there any way this is possible?

Comment: What are you trying to do, at a higher level? Why do you use reflection to instantiate a class rather than using new?

Comment: Cast it to your class? Or declare the variable's type as that class instead of Object.

Comment: If you're a Java beginner, you almost certainly don't need to mess around with reflection yet.

Comment: My teacher in school made a program that creates a password and I want to make a program that gets the password. But I don't know the name of his class so I programed something that I can drag in his folder and run it,  it finds his class runs it and changes the password to what i want. the problem is that I would have to access on the variable in his program where the password is safed and thats why i ask. That probably sounds stupid and there is probably an easier way to do it but thats the only way that came in my mind

Comment: If the password is a private field in the class, you will need reflection to access it. It sounds like this is the case, because I doubt your teacher has a `getPassword` or `setPassword` method on his class. Have a look at [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html) for a place to start.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer it helped me very much. But for some reasons the way shown in the link only works if the variable is public

Answer (score 1):

Using `Class.forName(nameNeu).newInstance();` is a bad way to construct objects unless there is a very good reason to do so.

Instead use a standard constructor, e.g. `Foo myFoo = new Foo()`

If you must construct an object this way, yes, it is possible to access the instance variables of the object. The problem is that your variable `pw` is declared as an `Object`. Object doesn't have many useful methods. You should cast the Object to a more specific class.

For example,

```
MoreSpecificType pw = (MoreSpecificType) Class.forName(nameNeu).newInstance();

pw.someMethod();
```

You can call `someMethod()` because it is a method of `MoreSpecificType` but it is not a method of `Object`

Answer (score 1):

If `nameNeu="my.BeginnerClass"` and your class has a method `foo()`, then you can write :

```
my.BeginnerClass pw = (my.BeginnerClass)Class.forName(nameNeu).newInstance();
pw.foo();
```

But it's more straightforward to do :

```
my.BeginnerClass pw = new my.BeginnerClass();
pw.foo();
```